# How to check if the input matrix is symmetric?

Tags: javascript

The code below takes in a matrix (`MAT`) and transposes the matrix, calls it `array`. The definition of the symmetrical matrix is that it should be a square matrix and the elements in the given matrix compared to the transposed one should be the same.

The given matrix below and transposed matrix should output `false` if checked for symmetry.

I did create an if statement at first to check whether `MAT[j][i]` and `array[j][i]` are the same but keep getting the wrong answer. It's not properly checking all the elements together. Could someone help with that?

Thanks!

```js
const symmetricMatrix = function (MAT) {
  let array = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < MAT.length; i++) {
    array.push([]);
    for (let j = 0; j < MAT.length; j++) {
      array[i].push(MAT[j][i]);

    }
  }

  
  return array;
};

console.log(
  symmetricMatrix(
    (MAT = [
      [1, 3, 1],
      [-1, 1, 4],
      [2, 1, 0],
    ])
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can create a copy of matrix and then transpose it and then check if it has same element at that index.

```js
const symmetricMatrix = function (mat) {
  const copy = Array.from(mat, (_) => []);

  for (let i = 0; i < mat.length; i++)
    for (let j = 0; j < mat.length; j++) 
      copy[i][j] = mat[j][i];

  for (let i = 0; i < mat.length; i++)
    for (let j = 0; j < mat.length; j++)
      if (copy[i][j] != mat[i][j]) return false;

  return true;
};

const matrix = [
  [1, 3, 1],
  [-1, 1, 4],
  [2, 1, 0],
];
const matrix2 = [
  [1, -1, 2],
  [-1, 1, 1],
  [2, 1, 0],
];
console.log(symmetricMatrix(matrix));
console.log(symmetricMatrix(matrix2));
```